# Laravel redirect www to non-www with htaccess not working correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following lines inside an `.htaccess` file which redirects a www URL to a non-www URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works correctly when trying to load the index route: `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`, but if someone tries to load any other route, it does not load anything, for example, if I try to load `https://www.example.com/about-us` it converts the URL to `https://example.com/index.php` and it doesn't load anything.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

My complete `.htaccess` is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
  
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.pdf|\.mp4|\.woff|\.woff2|\.ttf|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|favicon|fonts|font|videos|storage|pdf)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
    
    
  
    
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)">
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>


<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: It's possible this redirect happens after the rewrite to index.php in which case you'd end up with a redirect to the rewritten URL. Try moving these rules to the top of .htaccess

Comment: @apokryfos I have moved those lines to the beginning of the file, right after `RewriteEngine On` line, but same result :/

Comment: "I have moved those lines to the beginning" - If you previously had these directives later in the file then it's possible you are seeing a cached response. 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser by default. Otherwise, the directives you have posted, in the current order, look OK.

Comment: @MrWhite You were right, didn't know of the cache response when modifying these directives, now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Same result with those lines.